# How does what I did imply that $X$ is Normal $N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $X$, $Y$ be i.i.d, that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent, and that $\varphi_{X}(2u)=(\varphi_{X}(u))^{3}\varphi_{X}(-u)$. Also, let $E\{X\}=0$ and $E\{X^{2}\}=1$. Show that $X$ is Normal $N(0,1)$.

We are given a hint that reads as follows: "Show that for some $\alpha>0$, we have $\phi(u)\neq 0$ for all $u$ with $|u|\leq a$. Let $\psi (u)= \frac{\varphi(u)}{\varphi(-u)}$ for $|u|\leq a$, and show $\psi(u)=\{\psi(u/2^{n})\}^{2^{n}}$; then, show this tends to 1 as $n \to \infty$. Deduce that $\varphi(t)=\{\varphi(t/2^{n})\}^{4^{n}}$, and let $n \to \infty$.

Now, I've done all this, and you wind up with $\varphi(t)\to 1$ as $n \to 0$ by definition of characteristic functions.

WHAT I WANT TO KNOW IS THIS: how does doing all of this tell us that $X$ is Normal $N(0,1)$? At this point, this is the only part of the proof that I have left.

Comment: possible duplicate of [X and Y are i.i.d. X+Y and X-Y are independent. E(X)=0 and E(X^2)=1. Show that X~N(0,1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556030/x-and-y-are-i-i-d-xy-and-x-y-are-independent-ex-0-and-ex2-1-show-that-x)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That answer still avoids showing what I want to see shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to disagree that $\varphi(t) = 1$ for any $t$, since this would be the characteristic function for $X = 0$ a.e. However, suppose that you can conclude that for every $n$, $\varphi(t) = \big( \varphi(t/2^n) \big)^{4^n}$. Perhaps it might be helpful to realize that $\varphi'(0) = 0$ and $\varphi''(0) = -1$. Then
$$
\varphi(t/2^n) = \varphi(0)+ \varphi'(0)\frac{t}{2^n} +\frac{1}{2}\varphi''(0) \frac{t^2}{4^n} + O(8^{-n}) = 1 - \frac{t^2}{2\cdot 4^n} + O(8^{-n})
$$
and therefore
$$
\varphi(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(  1 - \frac{t^2}{2\cdot 4^n} + O(8^{-n}) \right)^{4^n}
$$
This limit should result in the characteristic function for $N(0,1)$.

Comment: Do you mean for every $n$ that $\psi(t)=\left[\varphi\left(\frac{u}{2^{n}}\right)\right]^{4^{n}}$ rather than $\varphi(t)=$?

Comment: No. I'm writing $\varphi$ for the characteristic function $\varphi_X$. You want $\varphi_X(t) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$, which will prove that $X =_d N(0,1)$. So, as you wrote above in the question, if you can deduce that $\varphi_X(t) = [\varphi_X(t/2^n)]^{4^n}$ you can follow my suggested solution to finish what remains.

Comment: Also, $\varphi_{X}^{\prime\prime}(0)=-1$, not $1$.

Comment: You're right! Sorry, the characteristic function is $e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$ not $e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2}$. I'll edit and fix the mistake!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell exactly what you did wrong from that one expression. If for every $n$ it happened that $\psi(u) = \big(\varphi(u/2^n) \big)^{4^n}$ then you could apply my answer to $\psi(u)$, but you want $\psi(u) = 1$.

Comment: It's okay; I figured it out and fixed it. I'm really sorry to keep bothering you, but there's just one last thing I can't get to work, and that's showing that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-\frac{u^{2}}{2\cdot 4^{n}}+O(8^{-n}))=exp(-\frac{1}{2}t^{2})$? I tried using logs, and then L'Hopital, but I wound up with a big mess in the denominator. Any hints?

Comment: No worries. Consider $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{k}{x} + \frac{c}{x^{3/2}} \right)^{x}$$. Before doing this, use l'Hopital's rule applied to $$x \log\left(1 + \frac{k}{x} + \frac{c}{x^{3/2}} \right)$$ then, deduce from this that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{k}{x} + \frac{c}{x^{3/2}} \right)^{x} = e^k$$. Now, since $4^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, replace $x$ with $4^n$ to conclude your result.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you so much; you're the coolest!