# If $X$ and $Y$ are iid with mean $0$ and variance $1$, and $T= \frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{ 2 }}$ has the same distribution, prove it is standard normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d. random variables with mean $E[X]=E[Y]=0$ and variance $Var(X)=Var(Y)=1$.

Let $T=\left(  \frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{ 2 }} \right)$ and suppose that the distribution of $T$ is the same as the distribution of $X$ and of $Y$.

Prove that $T$ necessarily follows a standard normal distribution.

It is not clear to me how to prove that $T \sim N(0,1)$ in absence of any other information.

Comment: You tagged this with "characteristic functions".  Perhaps you should try that

Comment: The characteristic function of $X$ obeys a remarkable equation, which you can then exploit.

Comment: The title is very misleading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$X$ and $Y$ i.i.d., $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ independent, $\mathbb{E}(X)=0 $and $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=1$. Show $X \sim N(0,1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556030/x-and-y-i-i-d-xy-and-x-y-independent-mathbbex-0-and-mathbb)

Comment: No is duplicate. i haven't information about X+Y or X-Y, only X,Y iid random variables with mean equals 0 and variance equals 1. no more information

Comment: It is not a duplicate but there is a similar approach. You can show the characteristic function satisfies $\varphi(t) = \left(\varphi\left(t/\sqrt{2}\right)\right)^2 = \left(\varphi\left(t/2\right)\right)^4 = \left(\varphi\left(t/2^n\right)\right)^{4^n}$.  Then consider the approach in the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/562891/6460